# Nightwatch: How to iterate over DOM elements and make expectations about them in a cleaned way

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm iterating over DOM elements and doing some expectations on them. This is my working code:

```
browser.elements('css selector', mySelector, function(result) {
        let dinamicSelector;
        result.value.forEach((res) => {
            browser.elementIdAttribute(res.ELEMENT, 'id', function(idValue) {
                dinamicSelector = `#${idValue.value}`; // creating a dinamic selector of element through 'id' attribute value.
                browser.expect.element(dinamicSelector).to.be.an('a', 'Testing if element is HTML tag: \'a\' (link)');
                browser.expect.element(dinamicSelector).text.to.match(/.{1,}/); // contain some text
                browser.expect.element(dinamicSelector).to.be.visible;
            });
        });
    });
```

This code works great but require `id` attribute on all elements and it's some verbose.

I would like to know if I can do something similar to this (more cleaner code and without need a common attribute for all the elements on which I want to iterate):

```
browser.elements('css selector', mySelector, function(result) {
        result.value.forEach((res) => {
            browser.element('css selector', res.ELEMENT, function(elem) {
                browser.expect.element(elem).to.be.an('a');
            });
        });
    });
```

Obviously this code not work because value of `res.ELEMENT` it's not a valid CSS selector.

Comment: Yes & No. **Yes**, you can relax your code a few lines if your read your `id` from a local, or global variable, or even better from your [page-object](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#page-objects), in the `elements` object (*recommended by me! RAWWWR!*). If the ID's are chancing dynamically, then find a another way to target the elements in your `expect` statements.

Comment: ***No***, since you are working with the `ELEMENT` IDs, then the only way to go about it from that point on is by using the same API commands (e.g: *elementIdClick*, *elementIdText*, *elementIdValue*, etc.). Let me know if you want me to draft an answer. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the clues.